# How do I write a nested COUNTIF formula?

Tags: excel, countif, sumproduct

There is column A for check-in date, column B for check-out date for 10 individuals(10 rows of data). Find how many people stayed over 5 days WITHOUT using a helper column.

What I tried (doesn't work)---

```
=COUNTIF(DATEDIF(A2:A11,B2:B11, "d"), ">5")
```

This gave me an error. Is there a right way to do it?

If I use a helper column, C `= DATEDIF(A2,B2,"d")`, and then do `=COUNTIF(C2:C11, ">5")` it works

But how do I get the answer without the helper column?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try something like this, `COUNTIF()` Function works with a range, while `SUMPRODUCT()` Function with arrays, so its best to use the latter one,

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(($B$2:$B$11-$A$2:$A$11)>5))
```

With helper showing that it gives the same output,

[image: HELPER_SOLUTION]

• Formula used in cell **C2**

```
=DATEDIF(A2,B2,"d")
```

And Fill Down!

• Formula used in cell **D2**

```
=COUNTIF($C$2:$C$11,">5")
```

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

`COUNTIF()` doesn't accept array constants (as far as I know).

• Formula used in cell **A17**

```
=SUM(IF(B2:B10-A2:A10>7,1,""))
```

You can also create a `COUNTIF()` type formula like this (the combination `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `ENTER`):

• Formula used in cell **A15**

```
=COUNT(IF(B2:B10-A2:A10>7,1,""))
```

**Note:** The use of double negative --> "double unary" which coerces TRUE or FALSE values to their numeric equivalents, 1 and 0. It's used in formulas where numbers are needed for a particular math operation.

Comment: I tried it. Its giving me 1 extra count

Comment: @Fryedeg Sir, what is your Excel Version, may i know that ?

Comment: 2010. I tried it again. when I put >5, it is also counting the 5. I don't have any with 6 days. when I enter >6 I'm getting the right answer. How do I fix this?

Comment: I tried Ctrl+shift+enter. Same result. It is including the number specified

Comment: @Fryedeg could you show me a screenshot, where it is not working for you, sir, you please check the solution, in both ways I have shown to make it more clear

Comment: I posted what I got as an answer. Please take a look

Comment: @Fryedeg Sir, please remove it from answer, you should not be posting anything in answer if its a query, you could have updated the same in your original query

Comment: New to this. Will update!

Comment: I updated the question with a new image. Could you take a look at the formula and see if you notice anything wrong

Comment: @Fryedeg Sir, please download and check what do you get the same error or not, [Workbook_Link](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlEkksoPTc2cg3EWX7btgmdUsu1a?e=dRgzkk)

Comment: @Fryedeg Sir, have you checked, I have updated with **2** more alternative formulas

Comment: I figured out the problem. My dates also have times included in the cells. The SUMPRODUCT formula is taking that into account. The other formula is not. Do you know if there is a way to exclude the time without altering the column at all. Thanks

Comment: @Fryedeg Sir, try this `=SUMPRODUCT(--((INT(B2:B10)-INT(A2:A10))>7))`

Comment: @Fryedeg Sir, is it working for you sir, please do let me know